# The method getConf() is undefined for the type recommended

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am getting this error in this line : -

```
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), recommended.class);
    conf.setJobName("data to be recommended");
```

The method getConf() is undefined for the type recommended.

Comment: Paste your whole class definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the method `getConf()` from a class in which it is not defined (and not in its superclass hierarchy). Java therefore cannot find your method and the compiler will not even build the class. Reference the location of the method you want, or make an implementation for this method appropriately.

Comment: what changes do i need to take

Answer (score 0):

If it is hadoop then include hadoop jar.

In short:

JobConf is part of the API used to write hadoop jobs.

```
JobConf job = new JobConf(new Configuration(), MyJob.class);
```

for more details go to below link

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html

Hope this helps.